# gevent and posgres: Asynchronous connection failed

Tags: python, django, postgresql, gevent

I'm using gevent to handle API I/O on a Django-based web system.

I've monkey-patched using:

```
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_socket()
```

I've patched psychopg using:

```
import psycogreen; psycogreen.gevent.patch_psycopg()
```

Nonetheless, certain Django calls so Model.save() are failing with the error: "Asynchronous Connection Failed." Do I need to do something else to make postgres greenlet-safe in the Django environment? Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 7):

there is an [article](http://habrahabr.ru/post/174717/) on this promblem, unfortunately it's in Russian. Let me quote the final part:

> All the connections are stored in [django.db.connections](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/db/__init__.py#L14), which is
>   the instance of [django.db.utils.ConnectionHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/db/utils.py#L55). Every time ORM
>   is about to issue a query, it requests a DB connection by calling
>   *connections['default']*. In turn, *ConnectionHandler.__getattr__* checks if there is a connection in 
>   [ConnectionHandler._connections](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/db/utils.py#L65), and creates a new one if it is
>   empty.
>
> All opened connections should be closed after use. There is a signal
>   [request_finished](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/db/__init__.py#L53), which is run by
>   [django.http.HttpResponseBase.close](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/http/response.py#L230). Django closes DB connections
>   at the very last moment, when nobody could use it anymore - and it
>   seems reasonable.
>
> Yet there is tricky part about how ConnectionHandler stores DB
>   connections. It uses [threading.local](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local), which becomes
>   [gevent.local.local](http://gevent.org/gevent.local.html) after monkeypatching. Declared once, this
>   structure works just as it was unique at every greenlet. Controller
>   *some_view* started its work in one greenlet, and now we've got a connection in *ConnectionHandler._connections*. Then we create few
>   more greenlets and which get an empty
>   *ConnectionHandlers._connections*, and they've got connectinos from pool. After new greenlets done, the content of their local() is gone,
>   and DB connections gone withe them without being returned to pool. At
>   some moment, pool becomes empty
>
> Developing Django+gevent you should always keep that in mind and close
>   the DB connection by calling [django.db.close_connection](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5c2/django/db/__init__.py#L44). It
>   should be called at exception as well, you can use a decorator for
>   that, something like:

```
class autoclose(object):
    def __init__(self, f=None):
        self.f = f

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        with self:
            return self.f(*args, **kwargs)

    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_info, tb):
        from django.db import close_connection
        close_connection()
        return exc_type is None
```